# I want to start learning Unix and Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I would like to start learning Linux. Can anyone give me a sources and some tips?

Comment: Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Linux® Command Line by William E. Shotts, Jr.](https://courseweb.pitt.edu/bbcswebdav/institution/Pitt%20Online/MLIS_Pitt_Online/LIS%202600/Intro%20Module/LIS_2600_%20M1_Shotts%202009.pdf)

Free, well written, beginner-friendly, step-by-step, comprehensive, and with external references.

And the sooner you get used to the [man](/questions/tagged/man) pages, the better.

Also learn to read what the screen tells. Skipping output is a bad habit. If you really don't want it, learn how to filter it out to keep it under control.